# how to exclude maven central repository from mirror and access it directly?

Tags: maven

we have a Nexus server for our Maven repository, but for some reasons that I do not know the nexus can not reach maven central, its status is : "In Service Attempting to Proxy and Remote Unavailable". 
this is my settings.xml in .m2 directory:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  <servers>
  <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>uuuu</username>
      <password>ppppp</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>releases</id>
      <username>uu</username>
      <password>ppp</password>
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>user1</username>
      <password>pass1</password>
      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
        <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://192.168.0.120/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

how can i configure maven to use central repo directly without going through nexus?

Comment: Use http instead https for central in Nexus configuration? and best would be to fix the configuration in Nexus...

Comment: It was HTTP and not working also, even I can not access to central with HTTP by browser.

Comment: Sorry I've mistaken that. Use https instead of http ...? ...Central only via https ...

Comment: I have changed all URLs to `HTTPS`, the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best idea would be to repair the Nexus.

But if this is not an option, you could replace the  `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` by `<mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>` and replace the `http:/central` in the repositories definition by the correct https url of MavenCentral.

Comment: I did, but now I get another error that says can not find a dependency in Maven central : `Failure to find antlr:antlr-runtime-repackaged:pom:3.2 in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`

Comment: does not Maven try to find that dependency from Nexus when it can not find it from Central? since when I mirror every thing to this old nexus repository it will find this dependency.

Comment: Maven goes through all the repositories before it fails. If this for some reason does not work in your situation, please ask a new question here on SO.

Comment: as you recommended I think it is better to ask a new question about fixing this damn Nexus! but unfortunately I have no access to the server running Nexus. I can only access to its web interface.

Comment: Why not talk to your Nexus admin?

Comment: there is no admin! I have started to work for a company recently. I am dealing with a legacy code base (it is a mess! I mean really a mess). the problem is that they have a lot of dependencies that only exists in the Local (Nexus) repo for this reason I can not totally disable Nexus

Comment: Ok, a Nexus without an admin just must be a mess and is also a risk that your manager/product-owner/whatever should do something about.

Comment: Is it that bad ? I mean that nexus needs a specialized admin ? we use jfrog with very similar config as @mhrsalehi and have no problems at all and no admin :)